# Post API getting invalid character '-' in numeric literal

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a POST function to insert data in my database using go.

**My Model:**

```
type Funcstruct {
    Name      string `json:"Name"`
    Status    string `json:"Status"`
}
```

**My post function:**

```
//POST FUNC
func (app *App) createFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)

    var data Func
    err := decoder.Decode(&data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    Name := data.Name
    Status := data.Status

    database, err := db.CreateDatabase()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Not connect to db")
    }
    _, err = database.Exec("INSERT INTO `func` (Name, Status) VALUES ($1, $2)", Name, Status)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error inserting data")
    }

    log.Println("Alright!")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

So i make one go build and after i make a ./nameproject

So, i go in the PostMan and make a post http request passing the Name and Status in form-data but i receive:

> 2019/07/12 22:20:38 http: panic serving [::1]:54600: invalid character
>   '-' in numeric literal

Comment: Based on the panic, it looks like the request body is not valid JSON.  Edit the question to show the request body.

Comment: I'm passing only "Name" in the postman. if i put form-data i receive the error described in this question, if i put x-www-form-urlencoded i receive this error: 2019/07/12 22:38:34 http: panic serving [::1]:54947: invalid character 'N' looking for beginning of value" i think it's something wrong in the parameters...

Comment: The code expects a JSON request body.  If you are posting x-www-form-urlencoded, then it sounds like you are not posting JSON.

Answer (score 17):

I experience the same issue while using form data in postman,I finally resolved to using json and it worked

Answer (score 10):

You should change `form-data` to `raw->JSON` and send like this:

```
{
    "Name" : "morefeizi",
    "Status" : "1"
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31058017)

Answer (score 4):

I experience the same issue while using multipart/form-data in postman.
And finally I solved it.

I use gin-gonic but I think it's the same issue.

my code before

```
type XXXReq struct {
    FiledA string `form:"file_a"`
}
var req XXXReq
if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&req); err != nil {
    DOSOMETHING
}
```

my code after

```
type XXXReq struct {
    FiledA string `form:"file_a"`
}
var req XXXReq
if err := ctx.ShouldBind(&req); err != nil {
    DOSOMETHING
}
```

So, maybe you SHOULD NOT use `decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)` to parse data.

Answer (score 1):

Send JSON Data from PostMan to unmarshal

[image]