# Golang file upload error upload "invalid character '-' in numeric literal"

Tags: go

this is my second day with Golang. I've encountered an error that says.

```
invalid character '-' in numeric literal
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015479/post-api-getting-invalid-character-in-numeric-literal), I can simply use "raw" body format in postman and all is good, however, I need to do a file upload and you can't do that from raw postman format. How can I get around this?

This is my controller code (I haven't implemented the file upload cause of this reason)

```
func Signup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var dUser models.User
    var signupBody requests.SignUpRequest

    requestBody, err := io.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(requestBody, &signupBody)
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&signupBody); err != nil {
    //  fmt.Println(err)
    //  helpers.ResposeFormater(w, err, "Something Went Wrong", 500)
    //  return
    // }

    defer r.Body.Close()

    switch {
        case signupBody.Email == "":
            helpers.ResposeFormater(w, "Email field cannot be empty", "Email field cannot be empty", 422)
            return
        case signupBody.Password == "":
            helpers.ResposeFormater(w, "Password field cannot be empty", "Password field cannot be empty", 422)
            return
        case signupBody.ConfirmPassword == "":
            helpers.ResposeFormater(w, "Confirm field cannot be empty", "Confirm field cannot be empty", 422)
            return
        case signupBody.Firstname == "":
            helpers.ResposeFormater(w, "First name field cannot be empty", "Firstname field cannot be empty", 422)
            return
        case signupBody.Lastname == "":
            helpers.ResposeFormater(w, "Last name field cannot be empty", "Lastname field cannot be empty", 422)
            return

    }

    //validate email
    if err := configs.DB.First(&dUser, "email=?", signupBody.Email).Error; err == nil {
        helpers.ResposeFormater(w, "User with this email already exists", "User with this email already exists", 422)
        return
    }

    //validate password
    if signupBody.Password != signupBody.ConfirmPassword {
            helpers.ResposeFormater(w, "Password Doesn't match", "Password Doesn't match", 422)
            return
    }

    hashPass, err := helpers.HashPassword(signupBody.Password);  

    if err != nil {
        helpers.ResposeFormater(w, err, "Something Went Wrong", 500)
        return
    }

    user := &models.User{
        Firstname: signupBody.Firstname,
        Lastname: signupBody.Lastname,
        Email: signupBody.Email,
        Password: hashPass,
        Picture: "",
    }

    if err := configs.DB.Create(&user).Error; err != nil {
        helpers.ResposeFormater(w, err, "Something Went Wrong 45", 500)
        return  
    }

    helpers.ResposeFormater(w, user, "Success", 201)
}
```

So far, I've only tried switching from `unmarshal` to `decode`.

I am fully aware this isn't much to work with so let me know if you need anything. An answer with a reference would be really generous.

EDIT:

**SignUpRequest**

```
type SignUpRequest struct {
    Email           string `json:"email"`
    Firstname       string `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname        string `json:"lastname"`
    Password        string `json:"password"`
    ConfirmPassword string `json:"cpassword"`
}
```

**raw body**

```
{
    "firstname": "Melly",
    "lastname": "Melly",
    "email": "test2@gmail.com",
    "password": "thepassword",
    "cpassword": "thepassword",
    "picture": "no"
}
```

Comment: We will need a definition of `requests.SignUpRequest` and the raw body you are sending, as it seems the problem will be in the json.Unmarshall call.

But first, try to add some print statements to see how far you'll get in the code so you can point out the line it fails on.

Comment: @zdevaty I've updated the question. I forgot to add the print statement conclusion so I'll just say it here. It fails at `unmarshal`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post API getting invalid character '-' in numeric literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015479/post-api-getting-invalid-character-in-numeric-literal)

Comment: @Aditya No. The answer to that question simply says "avoid form-data" I actually referenced that question here and stated that "I need form data for file uploads"

Answer (score 0):

This works like charm:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type SignUpRequest struct {
    Email           string `json:"email"`
    Firstname       string `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname        string `json:"lastname"`
    Password        string `json:"password"`
    ConfirmPassword string `json:"cpassword"`
}

func main() {
    raw := `{
    "firstname": "Melly",
    "lastname": "Melly",
    "email": "test2@gmail.com",
    "password": "thepassword",
    "cpassword": "thepassword",
    "picture": "no"
    }`
    var s SignUpRequest
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(raw), &s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

The output is

```
{test2@gmail.com Melly Melly thepassword thepassword}
```

Which suggests that there is nothing wrong with your JSON Unmarshal.

What is your version of Go? Mine is 1.20.